# Downloading a file with a type 'application/octet-stream' and saving it download folder to install

Tags: c#, php, .net, download, httpclient

I'm currently doing a proof of concept for my application to check for updates and if their is a new version then download that version and install it (prompt the user to install?).

I'm stuck on implementing the download part of the problem, I have an AJAX call with PHP that just returns a file but the type is "application/octet-stream".

```
<?php @session_start();

$filename = "\\xxx\x\Application\ka-v1.0.0.0.txt";

header("X-Sendfile: $filename");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');

?>
```

The idea is to expand this and check the database what is the latest version and based on that it will form the filename. Originally the plan is to do a scandir on the directory to get all filenames and check for the latest and compare that to the application.

On the Xamarin.Form my code is

```
        _client = new HttpClient();
    public async void GetUpdate(string uri)
    {
        var bytesme = await DownloadFile("https://10.0.2.2:8080/apps/x/ajax/ajax.get_download.php");
        File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), bytesme);
    }
    
    public static Task<byte[]> DownloadFile(string url)
    {
        if (!url.Trim().StartsWith("https", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            throw new Exception("iOS and Android Require Https");

        return _client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

    }
```

So the idea is that when the user starts the application then it will call GetUpdates. For now GetUpdate is tied to a button click event. So the idea on the code is that it will download the file via HTTPClient then write it on a Downloads folder.

In this state that code doesn't work

The next step that I haven't research is automatically opening the file to prompt the user to install the new update

Comment: "code doesn't work" is a useless description of the problem.  Does it compile?  Do you get an error exception?  Is it able to connect to the server?  What **specifically** is it doing or not doing?

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert but your code appears to be just setting headers without actually sending a file.  If it's not sending a file then there is nothing for the client to download

Comment: What **precisely** is your question? So far, looks to me like you need to **keep researching**, until you know how to have server send a file using php. Millions of php programmers worldwide have found out how to do so; I'm sure you can too. I'm also sure there are MANY existing StackOverflow questions about that topic. If that isn't your question, then you may need to start over, write a new question. Focused on ONE NARROW question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. NOTE: xamarin is not relevant; for http, its general c# .net code. I've edited tags.

Comment: When I say it doesn't work is the DownloadFile doesn't work, that means the File.WriteAllBytes or the GetByteArrayAsync doesn't work. 

For the headers, that's a good question. It does work to send a file. I also tested it before posting it here. Check this for reference: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve So the PHP part works, thank you for your concern and I'm one of the millions that were able to find a way. You can check the reference above for x-sendfile if you are not familiar. My question pertains on my question of the post which is "Downloading a file with a type 'application/octet-stream' and saving it download folder to install", my question revolves in Xamarin part of using HTTPClient, the issue is that I'm not sure if the GetByteArraySync (not throwing an error) or WriteAllByteSync are having issues.

Comment: Ah, ok. I went astray at the paragraph "The idea is to expand this and ...". I read that as being part of what you were asking about. I understand now that was intended as "background information". Disregard my comment about php :)

Answer (score 1):

Since doing byte download with content-type 'application/octet-stream' is unreliable on Xamarin.Forms I came up with an alternative way of downloading and installing a apk file.

Instead of capturing the data, storing it locally then running it afterwards, I changed that sequence to the API call to a default browser

```
        try
        {
            await Browser.OpenAsync("https://10.0.2.2/apps/x/ajax/ajax.get_download.php", BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // An unexpected error occured. No browser may be installed on the device.
        }
```

So the idea is that the application will get downloaded in the browser and will give the user to open it and install the update.

Comment: Seems like a good approach. Still, it is surprising if something went wrong just because of the content type. HTTPClient is a standard .Net class (not specific to Xamarin). Was this on Android or iOS? Could be some interaction with the platform's OS, that might need tweaking by Microsoft devs. OTOH, you did not give enough info about what went wrong in the first place. Two common mistakes: 1) calling an async method from a non-async context (e.g. a constructor); MUST be async all the way to the top. 2) instantiating new HTTPClient on every call (but first should work).

Comment: I have few inclinations why it won't work but I found a good alternative so I won't go further. In this case I'm doing it in Xamarin.Forms which is for both Android and iOS. For future reference though, one issue might be because of the content-type. I'm unsure if HTTPClient properly gets the data since the debug doesn't really throw any errors or result (probably timing out). Another part I haven't considered are Manifest, specifically Android Manifest (testing it on Android) for file permission etc.

Comment: *"since the debug doesn't really throw any errors or result (probably timing out)."*: You have not eliminated other possible causes. That symptom happens when app dev makes one of the two mistakes I mentioned. Especially the first one; misuse of an async/await chain, by starting it from a context that is not async. Failed data send would either get an exception, or you would get result that contained no data. "No result at all" is a programming error.

Comment: ... to clarify: if no exception is thrown, and result is never set (so method does not return) can only mean one thing: a deadlock. A deadlock is your (the app programmers) responsibility to fix. If that is the symptom you got, your app code needed to be changed. FYI for future reference, if you do any more HTTPClient work.

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier, I could do more research and I will find a reason why it doesn't work but the alternative works great so will just build on top of that. For the Async issue, I don't think it is because the browser is also doing await. If it's async issue then the alternative would also not work. It might be a deadlock which is my responsibility but was hoping someone in the internet can look at my code and see what's wrong with it would have been great.

Comment: I understand you've moved on for this question. At this point, I just want future readers to know that *"Since doing byte download with content-type 'application/octet-stream' is unreliable on Xamarin.Forms ..."* is not demonstrated by the evidence you've presented; instead I've listed two things for anyone using HTTPClient to watch out for.

Comment: Ah I should have worded that better, pretty sure using HTTPClient would work and possible but it's not as straightforward as I would have like